# Bad:How can i add the animation to my photos

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so i currently work on creating pages, and i have a problem. I want to make The animation(Fade in) on my appearing images When i hover on my button.Mainly i dont know how to add CSS code to appearing photos  . Below I show you my code. I dont know how to do that. Thanks for any help

HTML:

```
<div class="sekcja2">
    
    
        <div id="PojemnikNaZdjecie" class="FadeIn">
            <img id="myImage" src="naw0.jpg" />
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="PojemnikNaPrzyciski">
            <button class="PrzyciskiObrazka" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='naw1a.jpg'">1</button>
            <button class="PrzyciskiObrazka" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='naw1b.jpg'">2</button>
            <button class="PrzyciskiObrazka" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='naw2a.jpg'">3</button>
            <button class="PrzyciskiObrazka" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='naw2b.jpg'">4</button>
            <button class="PrzyciskiObrazka" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='naw3a.jpg'">5</button>
            <button class="PrzyciskiObrazka" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='naw3b.jpg'">6</button>
        </div>
        
            
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.FadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn ease 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to have the images' opacity set to 0, and when hovering it would change to 1. Notice that you would have to create a mouseout / mouseleave event to set the opacity to zero again, or something like that - if you want to. Here is some code example:

```html
<div>
        <img id="1" class="invisible"
            src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/explore/80688e429a7d4ef2fca1e82350fe8e3517d3494d/topics/html/html.png">
        <img id="2" class="invisible"
            src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/explore/80688e429a7d4ef2fca1e82350fe8e3517d3494d/topics/javascript/javascript.png">
    </div>
    <button onmouseover="htmlshow()">
        HTML
    </button>

    <button onmouseover="javascriptshow()">
        JAVASCRIPT
    </button>

    <script>
        function htmlshow() {
            document.getElementById('1').style.opacity = 1;
        }

        function javascriptshow() {
            document.getElementById('2').style.opacity = 1;
        }
    </script>
```

Notice that in order to fade-in images you must use a `transition` CSS property.

I also would do this code in javascript, using event listeners and maybe classlist toggle/add methods, there is a good amount of ways to approach this.

I hope this helps. If this is not what you are looking for, drop me a comment.